# finding a parameter to match the solution asymptotically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parameter-estimation

I need to estimate parameter $b$ in following differential equation in the interval $[-3:3]$,
\begin{eqnarray}
y''(x) = b\varphi^2(x)y(x)
\end{eqnarray}
where,
\begin{equation}
\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 -\sin\left[\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{x}{3} \right] \right)
\end{equation}
subject to boundary conditions,
\begin{eqnarray}
y'(-3) = 0 \\
y'(3) = 1/3
\end{eqnarray}

such that, $y(x)$ has two asymptotes $y=x/3, x\to 3$ and $y=0, x\to -3$.

To estimate the parameter, I proceded as follows,
\begin{eqnarray}
 0 &=& \int^{+3}_{-3}y''(x) dx -b\int^{+3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y(x) dx    \nonumber \\
 0 &=& y'(x)\Big{|}^{+3}_{-3} - b\int^{+3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y(x) dx \\
 1/3 &=&  b\int^{+3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y(x) dx \implies \int^{+3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y(x) dx = \frac{1}{3b}
\end{eqnarray}

So that, for any parameter $b$ above equality holds. Now we find two functions, $y_{min} \le y \le y_{max}$ . 
\begin{eqnarray}
 y_{min}(x) &=& 0 \hspace{1cm} -3 < x < 0 \nonumber \\
            &=&  x/3 \hspace{1cm} 3 > x > 0  \\
 y_{max}(x) &=& \frac{1}{6} (x+3)  \hspace{1cm} -3 < x < 3  
\end{eqnarray}

[image]
\begin{eqnarray}
 \int^{3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y_{min}(x) dx &<&  \int^{3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y(x) dx < \int^{3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y_{max}(x) dx  \\
\int^{3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y_{min}(x) dx &<& \frac{1}{3b} < \int^{3}_{-3}\varphi^2(x)y_{max}(x) dx \\
0.0305638 &<&\frac{1}{3b} < 0.517073 \\
10.929 &>& b > 0.64467
\end{eqnarray}

Mathematica estimates $b \approx 4$. How can I obtain better estimate without using numerical integration?

Comment: What do you mean by $y=0$, $x\to-3$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, that x axis is an asymptote to y(x) as x tend to -3.

Comment: Then you are looking for a solution with $y(-3)=y'(-3)=0$. By uniqueness, the only solution is $y=0$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, If I solve the equation with boundary conditions $y'(-3) =0$ and $y'(3) = 1$ in Mathematica, fine tuning of parameter $b$ shows that, I can make $y(-3)$ as small as possible. But if I start with boundary conditions $y'(-3) =0$ and $y(-3) = 0$, Mathematica declares problem as ill conditioned.

Comment: Using NDSolve with _initial_ conditions $y(-3)=y'(-3)=0$ Mathematica gives the correct solution $y=0$.